# Question about multiplying damage with decisive strike

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

So, reading another question about Decisive Strike, the answer was that it works the same as a critical, by multiplying its damage and therefore utilising multiple rolls and adding the totals, however, it's still not fully clear to me.

Let's say that in this instance a Monk 4/Swordsage 2 with Assassin's Stance, Fiery Fist and Shadow Blade (let's say the DEX bonus is +4) makes a decisive strike sneak attack unarmed on a monster.

Normal damage would be 1d8 via unarmed damage + 1d6 fire damage via Fiery Fist + 2d6 per sneak attack + 4 via DEX bonus

I know the example is convoluted but i helps me know which sources multiply and which don't. As I understand, with decisive strike it would be the following:

2d8 via unarmed damage + 2d6 fire damage via Fiery Fist + 4d6 via sneak attack + 4 DEX bonus

Is this correct? Is the fixed bonus also multiplied (in this case the +4 damage for DEX)?

And also, one little question on decisive strike; it says that every other attack before the start of my next turn is also doubled, yet the penalty only applies to the first roll. Does this mean that any other attack I get to make this round (by, let's say, Fire Riposte, or an AoO), also gets double damage without penalty?

Sorry for the convoluted question, but when I start reading supplementary manuals, even if they are the PHB2, things get more and more confusing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions here should be limited to a single question per Question, and this is perhaps an example of why. We already have a Q&A on your primary question, so I have marked this as a duplicate of that one (this is fine and normal, it helps keep information in one place and helps people searching for your question find the answer at the other question), but you have the extra question here. You could make this Question solely about the extra question, and we could re-open (or you could just ask that as a new Question).

Comment: I did look at that Q&A and I needed more detail on it, since I didn't know if the flat bonus applied to the multiplication or if the bonus die did too (the rule only says, roll the damage again, it could as well mean only the base damage), and since I didn't want to necro I thought of asking the question relating only to those details, I'm sorry if this is wrong. You do have a point on the extra question and I'll post that one in a new one if it's not a problem.

Comment: Given that A_S00 already answered both questions, I won't make the second question (didn't see the edit before). If it's necessary I'll reformat whatever needs be to have the Q&As as organized as possible. Whatever you think is best.

Comment: It’s fine—the “correct” thing would have been to put a comment on my answer asking me to clarify it more (which I would have happily done), or if that didn’t work, put a Bounty on the question to get more attention on it (which you can’t do yet because you need to have rep to offer to make a Bounty). But what’s done is done, and no harm no foul. Feel free to leave it alone (aside from accepting A_S00’s answer if it, in fact, answers your question—that you should do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multiply your base damage and any flat bonus damage.  Do not multiply bonus damage dice.

From the [SRD's section on combat statistics](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#multiplyingDamage):

> **Multiplying Damage**
>
> Sometimes you multiply damage by some factor, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage (with all modifiers) multiple times and total the results. Note: When you multiply damage more than once, each multiplier works off the original, unmultiplied damage.
>
> Exception: Extra damage dice over and above a weapon’s normal damage are never multiplied.

So for the damage factors in your example:

- **1d8 via unarmed damage**:  Roll this twice, this is your base damage
- **1d6 fire damage via Fiery Fist**:  Don't multiply this, it's a bonus damage die
- **2d6 per sneak attack**:  Don't multiply these, they're bonus damage dice
- **4 DEX bonus**:  Multiply this, it's a flat damage bonus, not a bonus damage die

Thus, your final damage in your example would end up as:

2d8 (2 * base) + 1d6 fire (Fiery Fist) + 2d6 (sneak attack) + 8 (2 * dex bonus)

> And also, one little question on decisive strike; it says that every other attack before the start of my next turn is also doubled, yet the penalty only applies to the first roll. Does this mean that any other attack I get to make this round (by, let's say, Fire Riposte, or an AoO), also gets double damage without penalty?

That's correct.  The attack penalty specifically says it applies to "this attack roll," but the damage multiplier applies to "any other attack you make before the start of your next turn."

Comment: So if a maneuver adds 1d6 + initiator level as fire damage, even if it's bonus damage due to an effect, the flat "+ initiator level" also gets multiplied?

Comment: @Karrion42 Correct.